# Dynamic change of tag value in formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can I dynamically change value of tag (i.e. id and name)?
Here I am providing static value for tag but I want to change it dynamically.
My code is :

```
    $scope.formFields = [ {
                    className : 'row',
                    fieldGroup : [
                            {
                                className : 'col-xs-12',
                                type : 'tag',
                                key : 'mytag',

                                templateOptions : {
                                    placeholder : 'Select...',


                                }
                            } ]
                } ];

$scope.myForm = {
                mytag:[{"id":"1","name":"data"}]            

                };
```

Comment: Ok so what's the problem? Why don't you create a function that does something like `$scope.myForm.mytag[0].id = 2` and `$scope.myForm.mytag[0].name = 'newName'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to send the values, then using these values to set it dynamically

$scope.myForm = {mytag : [{"id":"1","name":"data"}]};

$scope.setValues(value1,value2);

$scope.setValues = function(value1,value2){

```
 $scope.myForm.mytag[0].id = value1;
 $scope.myForm.mytag[0].name = value2;
```

};

Comment: Thanks!! It helped :)